# Am I reading the Arduino incoming data the wrong way using jSerialComm?

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port

Im writing a JavaFX application that has to comunicate with my Arduino UNO. For this im using the jSerialComm library.

Just for testing puroposes I've upload a very simple sketch to my Arduino that prints to the Serial a "Hello" word every 2 seconds:

```
void setup() {
    //put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Hello");
}
```

And in my JavaFX scene im reading the incoming data with this:

```
public void setDevice(SerialPort device) {
    this.device = device;
    device.openPort();
    device.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
        @Override
        public int getListeningEvents() {
            return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {
            if (serialPortEvent.getEventType() == SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED){
                byte [] data = serialPortEvent.getReceivedData();
                String msg = new String(data);
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I can read the data from Arduino, but it comes in a strange way. Like the string is sended in 2 diffent strings. Here is an image of the console output:

[image: Console Output]

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jSerialComm in default = NonBlocking mode. So what happens is (as pseudo code steps)

```
 LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED triggered
 get the char H
 get the char e
 Because we are nonBlocking we have to move on in the program
 Print what we have so far -> HE
.... do other stuff or check if other stuff has to be processed
LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED triggered
 get the char L
 get the char L
 get the char O
 Because we are nonBlocking we have to move on in the program
 Print what we have so far -> LLO
 .... do other stuff or check if other stuff has to be processed
```

So you could do 2 things -> change the mode to e.g. blocking while receiving (ensure a proper timeout to prevent deadlocks) or rewrite the function (my preferred way) to check for end terminators in the communication flow and then process the content of the buffer (which should be implemented in a non-blocking way)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer. I didn't knew about the blocking/non-blocking modes. I would like to know if you can explain me a little bit more how can achive the second solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: You find all you need here: https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/ and about the modes here: https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/wiki/Modes-of-Operation and those examples https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/wiki/Usage-Examples

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If it worked or gave you the right direction, please mark the answer as solved